# Can't type text into a textarea when it's value attribute is set - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, textarea

I'm writing a diary app in React for a uni project, please appreciate that I cannot upload much code as the school has strict plagiarism rules and runs checks etc...

I'll explain the problem in points:

- User enters diary entry in the textarea
- If they click the save button or anywhere outside the texarea, the text is saved
- Text is saved by firing `redux` action that makes an `axios` request to the `node` server where the journal is updated
- A `redux` reducer sets the new state of the journal and now I can access the journal entries using `journal.data.entries`
- I now have a `displayEntry` function that checks the date of the entry, and loads the entry content into the matching date in the journal. This works fine and correct data is loaded on the right day
- **PROBLEM** - I am setting the textarea `value` attribute to the return value of this function i.e. the `entry.content` if it exists or `""` if it doesn't. When `value` is set on the textarea I can't type into it anymore to update the content for that day or add a new entry to another day. Removing the value property allows me to type into it again

displayEntry() function:

```
displayEntry() {
    const { todaysDate } = this.state;
    const { journal } = this.props;
    if (journal) {
        for (let entry of journal.data.entries) {
            if (entry.date === todaysDate) {
                return entry.content;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    return "";
}
```

All help appreciated. If more info is required I'll do my best to provide it

Comment: Can't comment on your specific use case without seeing a full example, but when you set the `value` prop on an input in react it becomes a *controlled component*. You will need to hook into the `onChange` handler of your textarea to capture the user input and store it in an intermediary state or something and pass this back to the `value` prop.

Comment: You have just helped me see exactly what I'm doing wrong. I am handling the input with onChange and storing the value in state and then I am trying to override it with the return value of function. That's obviously causing a clash when I type. Thanks a lot I'll go back and see how to fix it!